# How to rename a folder with content in it? - PHP

Tags: php, directory, rename

I want to rename a folder with files in it but it doesn't work. In the database it's successfully changed, but the folder didn't get the new name.

**Code:**

```
if (file_exists("user/$log_username")) {
    rename("user/$log_username", "user/$un");
}
```

In the folder there're some photos and files, but I suppose the problem is that I want to rename the folder when it's running on the server. The user is logged in, when I want to rename his/her folder, but if I first log out the user the `$log_username` will be equal to nothing. Is there any solution?

Comment: Copy folder to new name and delete the old folder?

Comment: Ok, I will try it

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: @Andreas Copying not always an easy option as a folder might contain terrabytes of data and would make the server run out of disk space (or inefficient to say the least)

Comment: an update in 2019.. rename() works on directories with content and I'm running php 5.6 on the linux machine I tried it on. 
For those with similar issues, check that you (the running server) have the required permissions set on the folder to do this.

Comment: @OliverMGrech copying from and to the same drive is just a matter or reindexing the files. They are not copied for real, try it yourself and you will see that you can copy terabytes of data in seconds.

Comment: @Andreas you are right with that unless copying (actually moving) to a different partition or drive. This should always be considered. Thanks for your feedback! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy folder to new name and delete the old folder when the user has logged of to make sure it all works as it's supposed to while user is in.
Or possibly when session ends of users can stay logged in for ever. Choose what is appropriate.

```
// Copy the folder
copy("user/$log_username", "user/$un");

 //Update database
 //Some code here

 // When user logs out
 Unlink("user/$log_username");
```

Comment: [`rmdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) fails if the directory is not empty.

Comment: A bit unfair to downvote because I used the wrong function isn't it? I mean a friendly comment would be enough?

Comment: Whenever I vote a question or an answer I pause the mouse a little bit over the arrow and read the tooltip. It says: *"This answer is not useful"*. I would downvote it again but it is not possible: [`unlink()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) does not remove directories, only files. [`copy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) also copies only files, it doesn't work recursively.

Comment: @axiac, You are right. I see this notification `Warning: copy(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory`. I doubt how this answer got accepted.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
rename(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/myoldfolder',realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/mynewfolder');
```

Should work with an absolute link instead of an relative one

Comment: Tried this code: rename(realpath(dirname(user)).'/$log_username',realpath(dirname(user)).'/$un'); and it says: Notice: Use of undefined constant user - assumed 'user'

Comment: Don't use it as constant but as string instead dirname(__FILE__)).'user/$log_username'

__FILE__ is an PHP magical constant: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

aww. stackoverflow has reconfigured the code _ _ FILE _ _ without whitespaces ...

Answer (score 2):

You can just use linux command in php:

```
exec("mv $oldname $newname");
```

Comment: Only if you run own VPS or DS. Most shared hosting providers block `exec`